# Qual Front End Framework devo investir

Tags: vue.js, react, angular

Tenho vistos muitos posts e comentários sem contar inúmeras vagas de emprego que exigem diferentes frameworks FrontEnd como Angular(JS, 2, 4), ReactJS, VueJS que pelas lidas que tenho feito parecem serem todos capazes de resolver o mesmo problema, usam quase a mesma lógica de funcionamento sem contar que são todos para FrontEnd, mas a minha maior duvida é qual deles devo investir? Neste momento sei AngularJs, Angular4 para ser sincero tenho um pouco de vontade em aprender ReactJS e VueJS pelos inúmeros posts que tenho lido e aparentam ser realmente interessantes, mas será que vale mesmo a pena aprender todos esses ou posso me focar me ser bom nesses que sei para que qualquer desafio que seja resolvido com os outros com a tal suposta facilidade eu também não sinta desvantagem?

Agradeço e aceito qualquer opinião

Comment: Oi Adelino! Apesar da pergunta ser pertinente ela está fora do foco do site pois vai gerar respostas baseadas em opiniões. Sugiro pensares nalguns factos: Aqui no SOpt há mais perguntas de Angular que React e de entre as 4 Vue.js e Angular (1) são as que têm maiores percentagens de resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Sergio, tentarei ser focar me nessas questões

Comment: Há um aspecto interessante também, que é um facto adquirido por estatística : Vue.js é a que cresce mais. O que é natural pois era a menos conhecida.

Comment: @Shog9 sobre o edit, pode ser relevante: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6756/70 https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6369/70

Comment: A edição fez parte de uma série de edições semelhantes, precisamente para seguir a proposta do Fernando referida em ambos os posts — estavas só a querer chamar a atenção para os posts, caso o Shog não tivesses noção de que havia discussões sobre o assunto, ou outra coisa qualquer, @Bacco?

Comment: @JNat somente linkando os tópicos relevantes caso tivesse sido uma edição por outro motivo qualquer.